# Comparing Incidence Rate Ratios

Tags: incidence-rate-ratio

I am trying to compare incidence rate ratios (IRR).  This is what I have:

Group A (exposed vs. unexposed) IRR and 
Group B (exposed vs. unexposed) IRR

So how would I correctly test for the difference between the IRR from Group A and the IRR from Group B?  The question I would like to answer is whether the incremental differences observed in Group A are similar to those observed in Group B?  Please help!

Comment: Sec. 6.3 of Agresti 2002 (2nd ed.) discusses some options, including the CMH test mentioned by @JamesStanley  If you are an R user you may find the [R/S companion](https://home.comcast.net/~lthompson221/Splusdiscrete2.pdf) to this book helpful, specifically p.102 sec E.  The R function `mantelhaen.test` runs the CMH test.

Comment: Oops. That was more of an answer than I was intending.  Perhaps @James-Stanley wants to incorporate it into his.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you could either apply a Mantel-Haenszel test for whether the impact of the exposure factor differs between groups A and B (basically a stratified chi-squared test), or almost equivalently, model with Poisson regression and include an interaction term between exposure and group status to test whether these differ (EDIT: I mean whether exposure differs by group here too)

Wikipedia is (for once) not very verbose on this subject, but does give a two-liner summary.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics